# Create a basic batch file that runs via the command prompt

Tags: file, batch-file

START CMD.EXE

run "" "ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable"

I am trying to run the ewfmgr in the command prompt via a script.   But this just opens the command prompt and nothing runs.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why can't you just run 'ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable' from the batch-file itself?

Comment: Run is not a command and it makes no sense to use Start and cmd exe together.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a batch-file with the following code, and execute that:

```
start ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Did it work? If so you should mark my answer as correct, else noone will know if we should still help you.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Tried it and it errors out.   I need to run that command from the command prompt, which if I type it in with the command prompt open, I can type ewfmgr c: -commitanddisable and it will show me the results that it has been disabled.   I was looking to make that into a batch file.   Thanks.

Comment: And without the start before it? Also what are the errors it gives